# Text mesh not visible on a container

Tags: unity, camera, text, position

I have probably dumb problem with a text-mesh game object. I want to use it as a title on a top of container. I will give you all information that you need to find a problem.
I'm using pixel font `Tripfive`.

1. In game result:

[image: 1]

2. In scene result:

[image: 2]

3D:
[image]

3. text gameObject settings:

[image: 4]

4. all other settings that can be realted to the scene:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Additional information: camera is a cinemachine.

Comment: It looks like your container is a UI object. Have you considered using UI Text or TextMeshProGUI to nestle your text into the UI drawing pass?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I've decided to change the font because it's unsupported for ui (text mesh).